# MarkLogic REST URL not working in Chrome browser

Tags: rest, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have created MarkLogic REST port on 6000 (say). The database contains few xml documents.

When I call the following URL on chrome it does not work
`http://localhost:6000/v1/documents?uri=/transformed/1000004.xml`

However it works on Internet explorer.
This is something strange because I have created MarkLogic REST port many times and it has worked on chrome.

Can anyone please help with what might be the reason??

N.B : Application uses 'application-level' authentication and default user is 'admin (admin)'

Answer (score 0):

MarkLogic will be responding the same way regardless of the browser; I think the most likely problem is with Chrome's presentation of the results. Use the "View Source" option and you should see the XML.